# RegularExpressionValidator allows only links

Tags: .net, regex, reg-expressionvalidator

I have a TextBox on my projects. I want user to write here only links from `Vimeo`. How can I do it with `RegularExpressionValidator`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that should allow you to validate the Vimeo videos links:

```
vimeo\.com/(?:.*#|.*/videos/)?([0-9]+)
```

You may want to add http or https at the beginning.